# Query on output of the C program

Tags: c

I have executed a program and found the output.But I'm not satisfied about the working of the program.

o/p of the code:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 4 4
```

I put the following code along with the query in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int  main( ) 
{ 
    static int a[ ] = {0,1,2,3,4}; 
    int *p[ ] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int **ptr = p;
    ptr++;                        
    printf("%d",*ptr); //It displays me the output for the this line as -170 why?
    printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr); 
    *ptr++; 
    printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr); 
    *++ptr; 
    printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr); 
    ++*ptr; 
    printf(“\n %d %d %d”, ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr); 
}
```

Comment: _"stalk overflow"_ is nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printing the address of `a[1]` here because *ptr is pointing to a[1] element 
so

```
  printf("%u",*ptr); // prints the address of a[1] element
  printf("%u",&a[1]); // check this statement you will get the same values
```

To print the value use another `*` like `printf("%d",**ptr);` it prints `a[1]` value that is `1`
**Consider**

```
   a[0] -> 0  a[1] -> 1 a[2] -> 2 a[3] -> 3 a[4] - > 4
   1000       1004      1008      2012      2016  -> Addresses

   p[0] -> 1000  p[1] -> 1004  p[2] -> 1008  p[3] -> 2012  p[4] -> 2016
   4000          4004          4008          4012          4016 -> Addresses

   ptr - > 4000
   8000 -> Address
```

This is what happens in your first 3 stataments.Now

```
ptr++ ==> ptr = ptr + 4 ; ptr = 4000 + 4 -> ptr = 4004

so printf("%u %u %u %u",&ptr,ptr,*ptr,**ptr);

&ptr prints address of ptr    8000
 ptr prints address of p[1]   4000
*ptr prints value in p[1]     1004 (value in p[1] is address of a[1])
**ptr prints value of a[1]      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically giving `printf` a pointer, which can result in seemingly random values (it contains a memory address). If you wanted to give printf the *value* of the thing pointed to, you'd have to dereference it twice instead of only once (which should result in the expected value).

Comment: Will it give negative value also?

Comment: @V.ARUNNagarajan It gives me `1` when I test it (it's dereferencing `ptr + 1`, resulting in `a + 1`, so it dereferences that, resulting in `1`) ... is this what you wanted?

Comment: @V.ARUNNagarajan : Here;s the link to ideone: http://ideone.com/FTk4g1, Your code is basically printing the address of some variable.

Answer (score 0):

int *p[] --> is an array of pointers
The memory structure would be like

```
         p(0x100)------>p[0](0x200)
                        ++
                        p[1](0x204)
                        ++
                        p[2](0x208)

        ptr=p
        ++
        ptr+1 will be (0x104)
```

In case of your program the ptr++ will point to next address of p. This is because p is array here and array is contiguous. when you dereference it ,it will print the next value of p array which is a+1